# Yii 2 Update All Not IN

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-model

Based on the code below, I want to update all in customer to status 1 where status = 2. However, i want to run the code below where customer_id not in (1, 3, 5, 8).

```
$customerNotIn = array(1, 3, 5 ,8);
Customer::updateAll(['status' => 1], 'status = 2');
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition can be in the format of what you'd put in a `->where()`, so in your case would be:

```
$customerNotIn = array(1, 3, 5 ,8);
Customer::updateAll(['status' => 1], ['AND', 
    'status = 2', 
    ['NOT IN', 'status', $customerNotIn]
]);
```

Comment: this is not correct. this will change to status 1 where not in 1,3,5,8. what i want is to change status to 2. but not in customer_id = 1,3,5,8

Comment: You mean you need both conditions? I don't understand. What the final status should be and under what condition(s)?

Comment: The use the `AND` operator to concat conditions, just as you would in a where block

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct answer

```
Customer::updateAll(['status' => 1], ['AND',['status'=>1],['NOT IN','customer_id',[1, 3, 5 ,8]]]);
```

jayeshprajapati.7027@gmail.com

Comment: What is different from your answer and given answer